# Is it possible to get flutter SDK version during application runtime?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using fvm, so multiple flutter SDK versions are installed and I want to be able to get, if possible, flutter SDK version during application runtime to verify that correct version was used during build, for example, when I compile manually in Xcode.